# C# - Why does the first iteration of this loop run slower than the rest?

Tags: c#, caching, runtime, benchmarking

I'm doing a bit of benchmarking to test something. I've got a large array of 100 million 64 bit ints, I randomly choose 10 million of those and do a few operations. The indexes are randomly chosen because I'm trying to keep the CPU from caching as much as I can, while still getting an accurate benchmark. The first iteration of the loop takes about .3 seconds, with all of the others only taking .2 seconds. My only guess is that parts of cone[] are still in cache, but I would think with an array of that size it wouldn't be able to store so much. Any other thoughts?

Perhaps a JIT issue?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Int64[] cone = new Int64[100000001];

        for (int m = 0; m < 20; ++m)
        {
            int[] num2 = new int[10000001];
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            {
                num2[i] = rand.Next(100000000);
            }

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            {
                cone[num2[i]] = i;
                if (cone[i] > 0) ++cone[i];

            }

            DateTime finish = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan elapsed = finish - start;

            Console.WriteLine("Took: {0}", elapsed);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Use the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: @SLaks I'm reading up on the Stopwatch class. Is it just more accurate compared to the DateTime thing I did?

Comment: It's most likely because you are allocating the memory on the first iteration. On repeat iterations, it will continue to use the 64-bit int array, and reallocate the second (much smaller array).

Comment: @pickypg The timer doesn't start until after everything is allocated, unless value types aren't allocated at declaration (I'm pretty sure they are)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be the code is Jitted the first time you hit the loop. The compile time is what's making it slow? I ran a C++ version of your code and it seems to have about the same latency for every iteration.

Comment: That's a good idea, I should have tried it in C++ too. If there's no difference with C++, it's probably a JIT issue. It's a small bit of code, I figured the whole thing would just be Jitted at start.